# constructor in React not being called upon component being instantiated

Tags: reactjs, constructor

I am new to React.js so I am still trying to understand how constructors work with it.

I have a default constructor that sets the name property to "Ryan". But when I create a Greeting component the name is not being set to Ryan by default. What am I missing?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Greeting extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
      this.props.name = 'Ryan';
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Hello {this.props.name}!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class LotsOfGreetings extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', top: 50}}>
        <Greeting/>
        <Greeting name='Rexxar' />
        <Greeting name='Jainaa' />
        <Greeting name='Valeera' />
        <Greeting/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result

```
Hello ! 
Hello Rexxar! 
Hello Jainaa! 
Hello Valeera!
Hello !
```

It should be

```
    Hello Ryan! 
    Hello Rexxar! 
    Hello Jainaa!
    Hello Valeera! 
    Hello Ryan!
```

Comment: Read a bit more about the difference between component props and state. You'll find your answer there. Props should never be altered and are inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Consider props as a read-only value passed to the component.

It looks like you'd like to set a default value when a prop is not passed.

In that case, you'd need to set the default value elsewhere instead of updating the prop.

```
class Greeting extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Hello {this.props.name || 'Ryan'}!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In the code above, 'Ryan' is used when `this.props.name` is falsy.

Or you can use `defaultProps`.

```
class Greeting extends Component {
    static defaultProps = { name: 'Ryan' };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Hello {this.props.name}!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does this not work either in the constructor?   this.state = { name: 'Ryan'};

Comment: @user3312266 Would you be able to share the code using `this.state`? You can use the state, but in this case it'd not make sense though as you should use `this.state` normally for internally "state" management, not for values passed as props.

Answer (score 0):

A React component should never modify its own props. From the documentation:

> React is pretty flexible but it has a single strict rule:
>
> **All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props.**

*Source:* https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

You should instead look to manipulate the state. You can get an overview of state from this documentation:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
And Read [the official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) about the constructor and props.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Greeting extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Hello {this.props.name || 'Ryan'}!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```